# serverless framework AWS pseudo parameters stack name

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

## Question

- What is the correct way to get the output of a cloudformation stack in a `serverless.yml` file without hardcoding the stack name?

## Steps

I have a `serverless.yml` file where I import a cloudformation template to create an ElastiCache cluster.

When I try to do so, I get this error:

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Invalid variable reference syntax for variable AWS::StackName. You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info.
```

In my file I'd like to expose as an environment variable the ElastiCacheAddress output from the cloudformation stack. I am using the [serverless pseudo-parameters plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-pseudo-parameters/) to get the output:

```yaml
# Here is where I try to reference the CF output value
service: hello-world

provider:
  name: aws
  # ...
  environment:
    cacheUrl: ${cf:#{AWS::StackName}.ElastiCacheAddress}

# Reference to the CF template
resources: 
  - '${file(./cf/cf-elasticache.yml)}'
```

The CF template is the one from the [AWS Samples GitHub repository](https://github.com/aws-samples/startup-kit-templates/blob/master/templates/elasticache.cfn.yml).

The snippet with the output is here:

```yaml
  ElastiCacheAddress:
    Description: ElastiCache endpoint address
    Value: !If [ IsRedis, !GetAtt ElastiCacheCluster.RedisEndpoint.Address, !GetAtt ElastiCacheCluster.ConfigurationEndpoint.Address]
    Export:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ElastiCacheAddress
```

Comment: is the resource "ElastiCacheAddress" contained within an Output section? You need to declare the output section before you can actually reference an output resource

Comment: Hi @pkarfs. Yes, the ElastiCacheAddress is in the output section of the CF template. Here's the entire file. https://github.com/aws-samples/startup-kit-templates/blob/master/templates/elasticache.cfn.yml

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround to get your way through these syntax caveats.
In this case, I would suggest you to create a `custom` node to set variables you would want to reuse. You can then reference these variables using Serverless Framework syntax only, to avoid that error, like so:

```
# Here is where I try to reference the CF output value
service: hello-world

custom:
  stackName:'#{AWS::StackName}'

provider:
  name: aws
  # ...
  environment:
    cacheUrl: ${cf:${self:custom.stackName}.ElastiCacheAddress}

# Reference to the CF template
resources: 
  - '${file(./cf/cf-elasticache.yml)}'
```